# Puedo agregar vídeos de Youtube a mi aplicación de esta manera, sin tener problemas?

Tags: google-play, google-play-console

Estoy desarrollando una app que es como una Red Social, Cada usuario tiene su perfil y en el le pueden publicar texto y emojis, mi pregunta es si agrego una función para que los usuarios agreguen vídeos de youtube a su perfil o compartan en otro perfil de otro usuario sin usar la api de youtube, en lugar de la api agregaría un webview y dentro de este el código html del vídeo para poder reproducirlo... no tendría ningún problema por no utilizar la api de youtube?

quiero aclarar que mi app no intenta descargar vídeos de youtube por si un listillo pregunta.

Gracias por tu atención.

Comment: Se puede, ya que solo vas a publicar urls de videos Youtube. Recuerda que si deseas opinión, puedes preguntar en [chat], de otra forma revisa [ask], saludos.

Comment: No veo porque tendrías problema, Youtube pone a disposición el código de inserción, pues para poder compartirlos en otros medios. Los blog lo hacen a cada rato

Comment: @Jorgesys . no agregaria solo urls, agreagaria el reporductor en html que proporciona youtube para sitios web.

Comment: @Yussef mi pregunta llega desde una duda que surgió al ver el resultado y ver que con la api de youtube si salen anuncios que eso es algo positivo para los creadores de los videos, en cambio en html no e visto que salga ningún anuncio.

Comment: Seguramente tienes un bloqueador de anuncios, porque de no tenerlo salen en todos lados

Comment: @Yussef No bro uso un celular con android 10 e cambiado el id de publicidad para ver si ese era el problema y nada. no uso bloqueador de anuncios manejo el android lo mas puro posible tampoco nada de root.